# Tapkey returns 400 bad request invalid_grant

Tags: authentication, token, tapkey

Hi when exchanging access tokens through https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token api,
I get error code 400 with error message invalid_grant

Comment: Hi, can you add some more details about the request? Where do you get the access token from? How does the request body look like? Can you provide a decoded and unsigned access token and remove sensitive data. Please do not send the signed one, as they are like password.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the solution when calling API for access token the issue wax that the timestamps I was sending were before current time