# Tapkey Token Exchange returns 400 bad request invalid_grant

Tags: authentication, token, tapkey

regarding tapkey token exchange flow:
when exchanging access tokens through https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token api, I get error code 400 with error message invalid_grant

I am aware of a similar question and the solution in: [Tapkey returns 400 bad request invalid_grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69256066/tapkey-returns-400-bad-request-invalid-grant)

My jwt token contains of the following:
Header:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256"
}
```

Payload:

```
{
  "algorithm": "RS256",
  "audience": "local",
  "iat": 1633339589,
  "exp": 1633343189,
  "issuer": "tapkey",
  "subject": "myIpUserID1"
}
```

Before I make the API call I generate the jwt token with `"iat": Time.now.to_i` and `"exp": Time.now_to_i + 3600`, the call is done a few seconds later, manually.

Beforehand I created a IdentityProviderUser via API with the `"IpID": "myIpUserID1"`, and got a success response with a new User-ID (ID).
I also tried to make the https://login.tapkey.com/connect/token api-call with "subject" to be set to that returned User-ID, but that gave me the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

The payload field for the UserId is expected to be "sub" not "subject"

Comment: Thanks, but still the same error message
    -    
also: should sub be the User ID which was returned when creating the Identity Provider User? Or should it be "myIPUserID1"?

Comment: Ok, I also was doing the issuer and the audience wrong... it worked with myIPUserID